# How to apply a function to each element of a list without for loops or lambda functions?

Tags: python, list, function

For example, let's say I have a list:

```
integer_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I want to plug each element of the list into a formula, like (x*5)+1. Right now I am doing  `integer_list[0] * 5 + 1` How would I then get the answer from that and multiply every item in the set by it?

Please help!

Comment: "How to loop without a loop" is like asking "how to cook without fire". This is literally the *point* of loops. Why are you actively avoiding the obvious, correct solution? Is this some silly online programming exercise that forbids doing things the intuitive way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe the instructor doesn't count list comprehensions `integer_list = [i * 5 + 1 for i in integer_list]` even though there is a "for". Maybe `map`? `def doit(val): return val * 5 + 1` then `list(map(doit, integer_list))`?

Comment: Of course there's always `numpy.array(integer_list) * 5 + 1`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it's forbidden in the programming exercise, yes. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no lambda no cry

```
def f(x):
    return (x*5)+1

result = list(map(f, integer_list))
```